# Active Directory DNS and Forest Root Domains

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, subdomain, internal-dns, dns-zone

I am a little confused on the proper active directory configurations for the forest root domain. Recommendations call for using corp.example.com or internal.example.com. However, what is the best practice if you own/manage example.com domain? (I own and manage example.com through PowWeb, a web hosting provider).

I want to be able to set up Exchange servers, Web Servers, and FTP servers within the internal (or Corp) network that will be accessible over the internet.

EDIT RELATED QUESTION: Let's say that I decide to use example.com as the root/forest domain in dcpromo.exe. Could I then create a domain corp.example.com, and have the same server that I ran dcpromo on join the corp.example.com domain?

Ultimately, my goal here is to have dcpromo create example.com in its DNS. If I make the root domain in the wizard corp.example.com, it won't create any entries in DNS for example.com.

NOTE: This would be the PRIMARY and FIRST domain controller in the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I linked to the definitive answer for your main question - how do you name your AD domain. For your second question, you cannot have a single domain controller in more than one domain, so you cannot have a single DC be both the DC for the root of your tree, and a subdomain of that tree.

Comment: Thank you! .... I notice I was voted down. I get negative points if the question was already asked?

Comment: Yes, you'll get down voted for not doing research, and that certainly includes here and Google (which will often point here.)